# Printing to the console a List type is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I print to console out a List, or Map in Flutter?

The regular way of outputting data is by doing `print('something')`, but when adding a List or Map, the console says:

> flutter: [Instance of 'ListItem']

What's the correct way of checking the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably that's a `List<ListItem>`. If you'd like to see more details, override `toString` in your `ListItem` class.

```
@override
String toString() => 'ListItem a=$a b=$b';
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part `'ListItem a=$a b=$b'`

Comment: if your class had member variables a and b it would be useful to print them in `toString`

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thanks!